# How can I resolve "Body has already been consumed" error?

Tags: service-worker, blazor-webassembly

I stepped over a post, that describes, [how to add a notification](https://whuysentruit.medium.com/blazor-wasm-pwa-adding-a-new-update-available-notification-d9f65c4ad13), when in a Blazor Wasm an update is available. I exactly followed the instruction but did not modify `service-worker.js` but `service-worker.published.js` because I wanted to test it in production. I also added the "periodically check for updates" mentioned at the bottom of the post.

Everything works fine in Chrome, Edge and Safari but not in Firefox. When I upload an update, after a while, the service worker checks for updates and all browsers show the notification button. Clicking the button in Chrome, Edge and Safari results in reloading the updated page. Firefox gets stuck at the loading screen and displays the following errors:
[image: error messages]

Someone reported this as a bug at [aspnetcore](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39305) and since they found out it must be a Firefox bug also at [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1749298). There it was discussed and finally got the status fixed. But I still get this error with the latest version of Firefox.

How can I fix this?